# DotNet Core identity - it doesn't remember the user

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-identity

I want my DotNet Core site to remember logged in users for days, or even weeks.
But it doesn't. 20 minutes. And it's all.

I've already tried all possible options. Doesn't work.

All ordinary DotNet & OWIN sites of mine do it. DotNetCore - no! Please help !!!!!!

Update: I have added SignIn Code (which is typical) an User class.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIdentity<Core.Client.API.Models.User, Core.Client.API.Models.UserRole>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {            
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.Name = "**********.Auth";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
            options.LoginPath = "*******";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "**********";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });

        services.AddAntiforgery();
        services.AddMemoryCache();

        services.AddTransient<IUserStore<Core.Client.API.Models.User>, Core.Logic.Services.UserService>();
        services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<Core.Client.API.Models.UserRole>, Core.Logic.Services.UserRoleService>();
        services.AddTransient<Core.Storage.Api.IUserStore, Core.Db.Services.UserStore>();


        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);           
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }

//SignIn Code
public async Task<ActionResult> Login()
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        var u = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync("UserName");
        if(u != null)
        {
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(u, true);
        }
        return new RedirectToActionResult(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home", null);
    }

//User class
public class User : IIdentity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }
    public string AuthenticationType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Comment: And yes, my own SignInManager works good. The question is about standard AspNetCore Middleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer.

In order to control authorization cookie lifetime your **custom** *UserStore* should realize the *IUserSecurityStampStore* interface, not the ordinary *IUserStore*!

*IUserSecurityStampStore* asks for two additional methods: *SetSecurityStampAsync* and *GetSecurityStampAsync*.
And this is the clue.